# how to get id of submenu on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to get alert of id when user click of submenu.
Actually I am adding submenu of button click with id"menu_tc_1","menu_tc_2".I want to click of submenu ? and show alert ?

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1553/

```
$(document).on('click',".menuClick",function(){

 alert('jii'+this.id)   
})
```

Comment: Open your console, you have errors.

Comment: it is image error ..it not do anything.It is image error

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1561/

Comment: @adeneo ,you need to put it in Answer box , you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$(document).on('click',".menuClick li",function(e){
    alert('jii'+this.id)   
    $(".menuClick li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

This will solve your issue.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1569/)**

Comment: can we add seleted row? It is not vissible in which menu i click

Comment: yeah you could like adding some action class on li e.g. $(this).addClass("active"); and define css in "active" class

Comment: can you add in your fiddle

Comment: @user3530755, check it out my updated answer and fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to clicks on the menu elements, not the entire menu.

```
$(document).on('click',".menuClick a",function(e){
 alert('jii'+$(this).parent().prop('id'))   
})
```

You click on the `a` so find it's parent's `id`

http://jsfiddle.net/eHded/1565/

Comment: can we ADD SELECTED and unselected row something

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".menuClick ul li > a", function () {
    alert('jii' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Assuming you want the child elements that are added to the menu when you click the add button.

Edit: to add a selected class to the parent li element:

```
$(document).on('click', ".menuClick ul li > a", function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: can we ADD SELECTED and unselected row something